# Ruby/C logic to identify whether excel like cell position are overlapping or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, logic

I am writing a ruby code using it in Rails app, where I have to accept excel cell like structure from the user and also I have to validate those cell structure.

For example:

User shall be able to specify a block of cells by delimiting with a colon e.g. A1:B2 
shall cover A1, A2, B1, B2 cells in the form.

similarly user can input many position like

A1:B1
A2:C2
A1:F1

But the problem is coming when user enters the overlapping position for example:

A1:D5 and A2:C3 Also D1:E1 and A1:F2.

IN this case A2:C3 comes inside A1:D5 block, so user should get some error message(validation error) saying these are the overlapping position.

One logic I was thinking of is covert every position into an unique Integer value and using that I can differentiate, but so far I am not getting any logic to track this condition.

Let me know if any one has any idea on how to tackle this.

Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is simple box or rectangle collision detection—which is a widely-known and long-solved problem in game and graphics programming.

For example, see this blog post:

http://www.owenpellegrin.com/articles/vb-net/simple-collision-detection/

You'll want to convert the alphanumeric cell names (column + row) into integral (x,y) coordinates to make calculations easier.

So, from `A1:D5`, `A2:C3` they turn into coordinates: `(1,1):(4,5)`, `(1,2):(3,3)`.

A simple box collision detection algorithm will then be able to determine that both points `(1,2)` and `(3,3)` lie within the rectangle `(1,1):(4,5)`, therefore the second rectangle is completely contained within the first—i.e., you have overlap.

In your case, you'll also want to make sure your algorithm treats 'edge' collisions as overlaps. That is, `A1:B2` technically overlaps with `B1:C2` since they share the same 'edge' (that is, the two cells `B1:B2`).

**Note:** The 'naive' algorithm of checking each rectangle against the others to see if they intersect has O(n^2) complexity. If you're only dealing with, say, dozens of rectangles then you should be ok. However, if you need to check thousands of rectangles against each other, then you should probably be looking into dynamically constructing two interval trees, one for each axis.